# Авторизация через gmail java android

Tags: android

Имеется следующая проблема:

В мобильном приложение содержится авторизация через google когда приложение имеет applicationId "com.google.samples.quickstart.signin"(это тестовый id гугловской демки проекта) авторизация проходит нормально без проблем пользователь авторизуется, но когда проект получает свой applicationId авторизация перестаёт работать, при том условии что приложение с этим новым уникальным applicationId зарегистрировано в console.developers.

Возникает вопрос - по какой причине происходит подобная ситуация?

Буду благодарен за совет!

```
/**
 * initialize user auth
 */

private void userAuth() {
    gso = new         GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }

    SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    assert signInButton != null;
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
}



private void handleSignInResult(final GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        final GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        showProgressDialog();

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String accessToken;
                try {
                    assert acct != null;
                    accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                            LoginActivity.this,
                            acct.getEmail(),
                            "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_ME + " " + SCOPES);
                    return accessToken;
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), 125);
                    return null;
                } catch (IOException | GoogleAuthException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                try {
                    if (!s.isEmpty() && !isLogout) {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        getToken(s);
                    } else {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        signOut();
                        isLogout = false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
            }
        };
        task.execute();

        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Опишите проблему более подробно. Какие ошибки возникают? Желательно привести кусок кода, отвечающий за аторизацию

Comment: Ошибки никакой нету, открывается попап с выбором аккаунта пользователя после выбора закрывается и всё больше ничего не происходит, при повторном нажатии на логин окно не появляется и ничего не происходит. Но с applicationId "com.google.samples.quickstart.signin" работает без проблем

Comment: Вы JSON меняли на свой?

Comment: Да подменил на тот что в гугл консоли сгенерировало

Comment: что вам возвращаеться в  GoogleSignInResult result ?

Comment: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult@3889792
статус такой вернуло Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}

Comment: Не уверен, но для google api нужно два ключа, релизный и дебажный, мб проблема в этом? Ни разу с автортзацией не работал, так что прошу прощения если ошибся